# One log4j.xml - many scripts

Tags: java, xml, log4j

One of my utility jar files is used by different nix scripts, located in different categories.

Problem: unable to initialize log4j framework (unable to find log4j.xml). Solution, that allows to configure logger correctly while launching jar classes by different scripts - usage of env vars and force configuring using `DOMConfigurator.configure(pathToConfXml)` method. is it possible to avoid path hard-coding and configure logger inside of a script?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `log4j.configuration` system property to the configuration file as explained in the log4j [Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_Procedure) like

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml               Classpath-Resource
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/c:/log4j.xml      FileSystem-Resource
```

If you do not want to hardcode the path into the script than make it a script parameter/argument.